# In Ruby, how do I traverse a hash tree for two nodes in a parent child relationship

Tags: ruby

Lets say you have a hash like this:

```
{"a" => {
    "b" => {
        "d" => {}
    },
    "c" => {
        "e" => {},
        "f" => {
            "g" => {}
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write a function (using recursion) that returns true for a specific pair of keys (say `"a"` and `"f"`) if `"f"` is a direct descendant of `"a"`. The depth or distance between the two in the tree should not matter. All other instances (like `"a"` is a descendant of `"f"`, or `"a"` and `"f"` are on different branches) should return `false`.

Comment: _"I want to write a function [...]"_ – what's your specific problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def are_descendants?(hash, node, target)
  node_hash = hash[node]

  # check
  # 1) the hash does actually have the node specified to be the start as a key 
  # 2) the target key is direct child => done 
  # 3) if not: check if any of the children is a parent of the target
  # 4) if the hash does not have the node specified to be the start, then look inside one of the hash's inner hashes
  (node_hash && 
    (node_hash.has_key?(target) || 
     node_hash.keys.any? { |key| are_descendants?(node_hash, key, target) })) ||
    hash.any? { |_, inner_hash| are_descendants?(inner_hash, node, target) })


end

are_descendants?(hash, "a", "f")
  => true

are_descendants?(hash, "f", "a")
  => false

are_descendants?(hash, "c", "f")
  => true
```

Comment: Edited to allow the start node to not be one of the root's keys